# Is there a way to force a site to load a lighter version?

Tags: javascript, android, download, bandwidth

Well, i'm making an android app that access a site via webview, get info injecting js, and stuff.. And i'm worried about bandwith traffic. I still need to have some html elements (which i look for through javascript), but not all of them. Example, i don't need to load images. Is there a solution ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control image loading in the webview by the setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false) and setBlockNetworkImage(false) calls. This might not always be perfect, but it should block most images from loading.

The setBlockNetworkLoads(false) call would also block other resources, but you'll have to experiment to see how much you need to block to still have enough elements to work with.

See [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setBlockNetworkImage(boolean)) for the official documentation.

Comment: Yes ! I just saw some discussions about it. I found:
setBlockNetworkImage() and setLoadsImagesAutomatically()
I dont know yet if they work together. But i'm probably going to set both false. Thank you !

Comment: Yes, they work together, I looked at some old code and updated my answer. The setBlockNetworkLoads can also be beneficial if you want to block things like videos etc.  WebView is really handy and has a lot of features, that documentation link has some interesting methods listed.

Comment: Doesn't setBlockNetworkLoads block resources like css, scripts and these important stuff ?

Comment: Yes it does, but that can be handy if you don't need styles and scripts.

Comment: Actually, my webpage doesn't even loads with setBlockNetworkLoads(true). I tested setBlockNetworkImage and setLoadsImagesAutomatically. The first one must be true, the second, false. Both did the same thing, in my case. I'm going to use both. Thank you ! ++

Comment: Excellent, I am glad it's working for you - best wishes with your project.